# File sharing peer-to-peer in PHP

Tags: php, file, p2p, sharing

This question is really important to me as I'm developing a chat system in PHP, and I would like to allow users to share files between them with some sort of a peer-to-peer system.

Now I know that peer-to-peer have independent protocols and HTTP is not one of them but still I think it's somehow possible.

Like user A and user B are both connected, and A would like to send a 1GB file to B, there are 2 solutions :

- The lazy one : A uploads his file completely to the server, and then B downloads it, which makes the server more of a "storage" server than a chat server.
- The one that I judge good : User A sends file to B, without it being actually stored on the server before transmission.

Is this somehow possible in PHP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.webrtc.org - but to answer your actual question "is this possible in PHP" - no by definition. You want client-client communication, and PHP is server side.

Comment: Read your question again. Which part on the one that you judge good does not work with PHP?

Comment: @hakre the part where PHP directly opens a connection between the user A and the user B (kind of a socket), and then carries the flow that it receives from A to B directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's think about your problem.

Solution 1 looks like this:

```
User A <----->  Server -------> User B
                (PHP)
```

That is, the Server gives User A an upload form, then User A sends a file to the server. User B gets the file from the Server.

Solution 2 looks like this:

```
Server ----->  User A
Server ----->  User B
User A ----->  User B
```

This time, the server gives User A and B some code, which then allows User A to communicate with User B.

It should be clear that the Server can't be the one to send the file to B, and as the Server is the only place that PHP runs, PHP can't be used to send the file.

The language that User A and B can be guaranteed to share is Javascript. Luckily there is a very new specification to solve this problem called WebRTC (RTC stands for Real-Time Communication).

It's designed to solve the problem that you have, and you should use it. It is currently only in Chrome, and Firefox Nightlies. Recently, it has become stable enough that Chrome can talk to Firefox, rather than just Chrome to Chrome and Firefox to Firefox.

It should be clear that this is quite new!

Depending on your project and the scope of what you are doing, this may or may not be a good choice.

http://www.webrtc.org/ might help you out.

https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/file-hangout/ is a demo of what you are trying to do.

https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/docs/how-file-broadcast-works.html is some info on how to do it.